Integer Parameterization of degree 2 equation: $(6x+5)y - x - 2 = (6w + 7)z - w + 4$
Finding a complete integer parameterization of $(6x+5)y - x - 2 = (6w + 7)z - w + 4$ has proved challenging. Can anyone lead me in the right direction? This is related to some nonprofessional research I am doing on the twin prime conjecture.
Goals: Find parameterizations for x, y, w, and z which keep each one an integer regardless of input and cover every situation in which the equality holds true.
Thank you!

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

The degree of the polymials is $2$ , so in which sense is this a linear equation ?

@Peter Ah, my bad, I was thinking linear just meant no variable is a square-- but you're right-- two variables multiplied is degree 2. I'll fix that.

@user2661923 Is there anything I am missing?

Please follow the instructions in my first comment.

@user2661923 For what it is worth , I experienced a counterexample. An utter reasonable question (which sums of distinct factorials give a Poulet number) with a search-limit and the found examples was closed without any suggestion how it could be improved. This site has become a discussion site (many very opinion-based , but well received posts)  although it claims NOT to be that.

@Peter I don't understand what you mean by the statement that this site has become a "discussion site".  The protocol article that I linked you to asks you to provide many details in your posted question.  The protocol article is not asking for your opinions, but is instead asking you to provide details (a.k.a facts) that address the various bullet points.  For example, the request that you identify pertinent tools is asking that you review the course work that led up to this question (if any) and summarize the tools that you regard as pertinent.   ...see next comment

@Peter It could be argued that you regarded (perhaps reasonably) the linked protocol article as so onerous that (in searching for the path of least resistance) you double checked whether your posted question represents a true assertion.  I have no way of knowing whether my surmise is correct, however the timing certainly seems suspicious.  Anyway, if this is in fact what happened, then the protocol article inadvertently had a positive affect on the situation.

@ServingSpy why is this related to prime twins ??

Maybe this helps
$$(6x+5)y - x - 2 = (6w+7)z - w + 4$$
$$(6x+5)y - (x + 3) = (6w+7)z - (w - 3)$$
$$a = x+3,b = w-3$$
$$(6(a-3)+5)y - a = (6(b+3)+7)z - b$$
$$(6a - 13)y - a = (6b +25)z - b$$
$$6ay + b = 6bz + 25z + 13 y + a$$
$$(3a+y)^2 = 9a^2 + 6ay + y^2$$
$$(3b+z)^2 = 9b^2 + 6bz + z^2$$
$$(3a+y)^2 + 9b^2 + z^2 + b = (3b+z)^2 + 9a^2 + y^2 + 25 z + 13 y + a$$
This equation has many solutions.
The sum of 3 squares is a very dense set.
We can even express variables in terms of each other.
for instance $a=b,y=z$ reduces to
$25 z + 13 y = 0$
$$z = 25 k , z = -13 k$$
for integer $k$.
Or if $a=y=0$ we get
$$  b = 6bz + 25z $$
$$ 0 = b(6z-1) + 25 z$$
and the only solutions of that are
$b = -5,z=1$
$b=z=-4$
$b=z=0$
So on the one hand we have many solutions, probably to many to fit in a single algebraic parameterisation.
We can even write variables as functions of each other.
On the other hand some special cases only have a finite number of solutions.
So I suspect that there are $2$ or $3$ almost free variables and thus it is more like a relation than an equation.
Therefore I assume no closed form solution exists.
$4$ or $5$ variables is maybe surprisingly much.
Consider
$$(z + 2 - gh)(z - xy) = 0$$
this relates to prime twins if all variables are larger than 1. And I assume there is no parameterisation for $z$.

Why the OP sees a connection to prime twins is unclear to me.
